# How to get one function for multiple struct arrays?

Tags: arrays, swift, function, struct, swift3

I want array of struct as parameter to change in my function, if I want String to change I put text: String, but what to put when I want have test: ArrayOfStruct as parameter?

```
    func prizeCsGoArraySetup(arrayToAppend: here i want my struct ){
    if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "prizeArray") != nil {
        let demo = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "prizeArray") as! NSDictionary
        if let priArray = demo.value(forKey: "csgo") as? NSArray{
            for prizeItem in priArray {
                if let prizeVC = prizeItem as? NSDictionary{
                    let newElement : prize = prize(category: prizeVC.value(forKey: "category") as! String, name: prizeVC.value(forKey: "name") as! String, price: prizeVC.value(forKey: "price") as! Int, image: prizeVC.value(forKey: "image") as! String)
                    arrayToAppend.append(newElement)
```

I Want to add changeable struct array for 7 another arrays, how to do it?
I don't want to write whole function 7 times.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are asking. Can you reduce your code to an MWE that illustrates your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer , i need use inout before.

```
    func prizeArraySetup( arrayToAppend: inout [prize], forKeyText: String )
```

Answer (score 0):

Its easy

```
func prizeCsGoArraySetup(arrayToAppend: [MyStruct] )
```

Comment: Depending on what "changeable" in the question means, maybe an `inout` is in order here.

Comment: If i will do like that you will get error , Cannot use mutating member on immutable value